# Server Side Locks in Cloud Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm curious about the behavior of the locks that are performed when doing server side transactions on Cloud Firestore as mentioned in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=750&v=dOVSr0OsAoU

My transaction will be reading multiple documents and placing locks on them. My question is do these locks restrict all access to the documents - including concurrent reads from client code that isn't part of a transaction? Or do they only restrict writes?

If they do restrict reads is there any way around this - it could lead to severe slowdown in the app I'm working on.

Also in the case that a transaction tries to lock documents that are already locked - what is the retry pattern - how often does it retry, and is there an exponential backoff?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My transaction will be reading multiple documents and placing locks on them.

A transaction operation is first reading the value of a property within a document in order to perform the write operation. So it requires round trip communications with server in order to ensure that the code inside the transaction completes successfully.

> My question is do these locks restrict all access to the documents - including concurrent reads from client code that isn't part of a transaction?

The answer is no, concurrent users can read the content of the document even if you perform a write operation using a transaction.

> Also in the case that a transaction tries to lock documents that are already locked - what is the retry pattern - how often does it retry, and is there an exponential backoff?

According to the official documentation regarding [Firestore transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transaction_failure), a transaction can fail only the following cases:

> - The transaction contains read operations after write operations. Read operations must always come before any write operations.
>     The transaction read a document that was modified outside of the transaction. In this case, the transaction automatically runs again. The transaction is retried a finite number of times.
> - The transaction exceeded the maximum request size of 10 MiB.
> - Transaction size depends on the sizes of documents and index entries modified by the transaction. For a delete operation, this includes the size of the target document and the sizes of the index entries deleted in response to the operation.
>
> A failed transaction returns an error and does not write anything to the database. You do not need to roll back the transaction; Cloud Firestore does this automatically.